# How does memory management for Scala collections work?

Tags: scala, scala-collections

I can't figure out the implementation of some operations for Scala's immutable sequences. I'll use this as an example:

```
def example: List[Int] = {
  val list0 = List.range(1,10)

  list0.tail
}
```

Once the function finishes executing list0 is now out of scope. Would list0's head be removed from memory, or would list0 stay the same until the entire list is garbage collected?

Comment: Scala uses garbage collector like Java. So this list will be removed from memory when gc  will be launched by jvm again and realize that this object can be collected.

Answer (score 6):

In your example, the head of `list0` will be left to the garbage collector to collect, as nothing will reference it.  The remaining items (the tail), however, will continue to exist upon exiting the function (provided the result of the call is assigned to something).

Each cell in a list maintains a reference to the next cell in the list (or to `Nil`), but *not* vice versa.

Comment: Doesn't the fact that the head has a reference to another node prevent it from being garbage collected? Is that reference removed once it goes out of scope?

Comment: Nope, the garbage collector doesn't care if an item has its own references to other things;  it only cares that the item has nothing else referring to *it*.  As long as that is true, the item is a candidate for garbage collection.

Answer (score 1):

You are creating a total of 12 (possible) entities

1. `list0` - A list containing 1 through 10.
2. The 10 individual elements in the range 1 through 10. These might be interned, but that is a different discussion.
3. The return value, `list0.tail`, that contains elements 2-10.

Here is the conceptual memory graph just before the last curly brace, here are the **references**

```
          Somewhere on JVM Stack list0(head)->1->2 ... ->10
                                                 |
Top of JVM Stack, contains returnList with head->|
```

When the function is done, the reference `list0` will be popped off and will be eligible for garbage collection. Since `list0` is the only thing that referenced `1`, `1` is fair game for garbage collection as well.

Elements 2-10 as well as the returned list containing them will stay on the heap since whoever is referencing `example` is still reachable by the running code.

Hope this helps.